# Correct and secure way to access a custom SQL database in a custom PHP template file

Tags: database, wpdb, sql

I am currently developing a WordPress site with Wampserver64 (localhost). I have created a custom SQL database using a custom plugin, `wp_my_database`, located in the `wordpress` folder. I can access the database with phpMyAdmin. The database is not password-protected. The default username for phpMyAdmin with Wamp is root and the password is empty.

I also have a custom template file, `my_template.php`, in which I run some SQL queries (ex: loop through all my products and display them as a listing). I have no problem doing so using:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_database";
$cat_query = $wpdb->prepare("FROM $table_name WHERE product_category LIKE %s, $category);
...
```

My database does not contain any sensitive data (ex: credit card numbers), but I still don't want people to have access to it.

I plan on moving my site to a web host, such as Amazon EC2, and I am wondering if the block of code I am using to access my database will still work on there, if it's safe and if not, how should I proceed to prevent anyone from having access to it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need another table instead using custom post types and taxonomies? I imagine you’ll be re-writing a lot of code that the api already contains.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what to answer to your question. I have 50+ fields for each items and I am not planing on creating a custom page/post for each item in the database. I thought it would be simpler just to have a custom database and displaying each of the field on the page. My question is more about security/accessibility of custom databases in WordPress and not really about the efficiency behind it.

Comment: It looks like you don't have a custom database, just a custom table in the WP database.

Comment: Thanks! In terms of security / accessibility, does that cause any sort of issue considering the way I am using the custom table.